# Why don't drawers go all the way to the back of the cabinet?

Tags: drawers

I'm going to build my first drawer for my trailer and I just finished measuring it and then I decided to take a look at my kitchen drawers and see how they measure up to the space available.

There is 21.75" deep of space but the drawers are only 19" long. Now I get not going to the full length but not that much shorter.

For the space I'm building in I'll have 18.75" of depth and was planning on going with 18" deep drawers (measured to the back of the wood for the drawer). Is this not how it's supposed to be done or something?

Comment: the wheels on the slider will need some space.

Comment: Did you measure on the sides or just the middle?  Guessing there is a corner piece of wood holding the sides to the back of the cabinet or a stiffener on the back, that might interfere with the drawer going all the way back.

Comment: Dead space is not uncommon in factory cabinets. The factories that build those things don't live with them, so making one size of drawer for 3 sizes of cabinet and wasting lots of space on two of the sizes is not something they have an issue with, because they only have to build one size of drawer, and that makes the quarterly production numbers look good.,,